# In multilevel modeling, the problem of no variability in lower-level units nested within the higher-level unit

Tags: lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

Suppose that an observational study was conducted with 100 patients (i.e., 100 level-2 units). The researcher recorded whether a medical condition was present (coded as 1) or absent (coded as 0) in each patient at five different time periods (i.e., the level-1 binary variable of 0 or 1 was measured five times for each patient).

Suppose further that within each patient, the presence or absence of the condition was constant across the time periods. That is, each patient had the level-1 values of either (0, 0, 0, 0, 0) or (1, 1, 1, 1, 1). In other words, within each level-2 unit, there was **no** variation of level-1 values.

Lastly, suppose that we want to model the "effect" of patients' age on presence or absence of the condition "controlling for" differnt time periods. In R, the formula for the multilevel model would look like the following:

```
medical_condition ~ time_period + age + (1 | subject_id)
```

In this case, can we conduct a **multilevel modeling** analysis to test whether age is associated with presence or absence of the condition **when** the unit of analysis is level-1 binary values nested within the level-2 patients?

Comment: No, you can't / you don't need to conduct multilevel modeling in this situation. Your intended level 1 dependent variable - presence of a medical condition - does not have any participant-specific variance, so your data does not work in the multilevel framework. You can use single-level logistic regression with age and time as predictors.

Comment: ...though time obviously couldn't have any effect as there no time variation, sorry. So you could just use age as predictor.